# как реализовать оповещение клиентов об окончании оплаченного периода ? на php. Вывод в телеграм бот

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

не приходит в голову данная реализация, мне надо оповестить за день клиента что у него заканивается оплачиваемый период(на неделю, две недели... месяц)
есть база клиентов, у постоянных клиентов есть баланс,каждый клиент имеет свою программу питания(рацион для набора массы или наоборот для похудения...) каждый день курьер доставляет этот рацион. Как только клиент оплатил к примеру на месяц то менеджер оформляет заказы сразу наперед(на месяц) и получается что баланс в тот же день уменьшается и равен 0, тоесть только на баланс я не могу равнятся.

Какая есть механика для оповещения клиента за день? думал ещё о написании скрипта в отдельный файл и  запускать программой CRON.
P.S Сайт о здоровом питании.

Comment: Ну решение с cron нормальное, даже отличная. Что не так?

Comment: мне надо проходить по сем клиентам так как данная реализация зависит ще id клиента в базе

Comment: Всё равно не вижу проблем через cron

Comment: да, проблему я решил но есть минус один, если запускать каждый день через cron то уведомлять бедет каждый день пока клиент не продлит

Comment: Оповестили, записали в базу когда отправили оповещение. Ну и проверяйте было ли уже оповещение и от этого отталкивайтесь